# error when adding a element to a global variable of type List<File>

Tags: java, android

I'm having a error when i try to add a element to my variable fotoActiva.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{  
    if (requestCode == 1888 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        File ftemp = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() +
                "/QuickReport Photos", Globales.fileTimestamp + ".jpg");
        Globales.fotoActiva.add(ftemp); //error happen just here
    }
}
```

the file is not null, in fact i can handle and read the file without problems.
the previous code is in my MainActivity.java

here is the class where i declare my global variable fotoActiva

```
import android.app.Application;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
public class Globales extends Application
{
    public static String fileTimestamp = "";
    public static List<File> fotoActiva;
}
```

when the error occurs, using the step over in the sdk it sends me to the following line of code in the class ActivityThread.java

```
WindowManagerGlobal.getInstance().closeAll(token, r.activity.getClass().getName(), "Activity");
```

and in this step i have java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: One could probably assume that `fotoActiva` is null

Comment: Your List<File> fotoActiva is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize fotoActiva:

```
public static List<File> fotoActiva = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList fotoActiva = new ArrayList();